# Scatter data - scale x axis to complete range and interpolate remaining y data points

Tags: python

I have XY scatter data with random Xs as integers. I want output data with an even X distribution and interpolate the missing Ys.

I would create an array with the range of x and fill it. Then run a loop to fill the Ys in the new array and then interpolate the remaining ones.

This seems super inefficient to me though. Is there a better way of doing this?
I'm fairly new to python and wonder if a module like numpy has an efficient solution built in?

For clarification:
I have a set of scatter data like this after sorting

```
[[1 , 0.1],  
 [3 , 0.2],  
 [5 , 0.4]]
```

and want an array like this

```
[[1 , 0.1],  
 [2 , 0.15],  
 [3 , 0.2],
 [4 , 0.3],  
 [5 , 0.4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[numpy.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) is exactly what you are looking for.

It takes a function in a tabular for, i.e. a set of (x,y) and computes linear interpolation for any new x.

Consider this code that produces the desired result:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1 , 0.1],
 [3 , 0.2],  
 [5 , 0.4]])

# a requested range - we fill in missing integer values.
new_x = range(1,6)

# perform interpolation. Origina array is sliced by columns.
new_y = np.interp(new_x, a[:, 0], a[:, 1])

# target array is zipped together from interpolated x a y

np.array(list(zip(new_x, new_y))).tolist()
[[1.0, 0.1],
 [2.0, 0.15000000000000002],
 [3.0, 0.2],
 [4.0, 0.30000000000000004],
 [5.0, 0.4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).

As a simple example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,2,4])
y = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.6])

# do the linear interpolation
new_x = np.arange(0,5,1)
new_y = np.interp(new_x, x, y)
```

which gives a `new_y` of:

```
[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.45,0.6]
```